# Host a WCF Data Service in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

I've an ASP.NET MVC3 application, and now I would like to offer a WCF Data Service for heavy client.

I can generate and configure my WCF service, but when I try to call it, it appears that templates of my MVC 3 application are mixed with my WCF service, which seems to be normal.

How can I say that it should not use any template or MVC concept for this specific service?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to keep the UI code (MVC 3) and the service code (WCF DS) in separate projects, and simply add a Service Reference from the MVC project to the WCF DS project. Then code is both logically and physically separated, but of course they can coexist on the server nicely. When debugging your MVC project, Visual Studio is smart enough to also start up the WCF DS project.

Comment: Great! Only one more question, if we have a separate project and set it as reference, what would be its reference? E.g. My website is on http://mywebsite.com , the service is MyTestService.svc, what will be the reference? http://mywebsite.com/MyTestService.svc?

Comment: Well, you would of course be making these references in your development environment, not in production, so the actual name of the production system is not relevant.

You create a Solution with 2 projects: the UI (consumer) and the WCF Data Service. Then you add a Service Reference to the UI project, and click the "Discover" button on the dialog box -- this makes Visual Studio look for web service projects inside your solution. And there you go, you have a working service reference. When you deploy your solution, you automatically deploy both UI and data service.

Comment: Yeah but in facts, I've only to create the service, the client will be coded by a third party, so I only need to know on which url of my principal website it will be reacheable.

Comment: So you develop the service in your solution, and they develop their client in theirs, is that right? And do they refer to your service directly or do you regularly release a new version, that they then include into their solution?